# SubForm enumeration in priority-web-sdk

Tags: javascript, erp

I'm enumerating forms / subforms like so:

```
var pdqFormLoad = function(form) {
    if (form) {
        var
            i,
            col,
            subf
            ;

        console.log("Opened form [%s].", form.title);

        console.log("\nColumns of $s.", form.title);
        for (i in form.columns) {
            col = form.columns[i];
            console.log("  -- %j", col);
        };

        console.log("\nSubforms of %s.", form.title);
        for (subf in form.subForms) {
            console.log(
                "  -- Opening subform %s.",
                subf
            );
            pdq.startForm(form, subf, pdqFormLoad);
        };

    }
    else {
        console.log("No form.");

    };
};
```

Firstly I note that only the title attribute is provided. Unfortunately the "formName" parameter of the startSubForm function requires the internal form name, rather than the title descriptor.

```
/* Debug output */
Connectiong to https://www.eshbelsaas.com/ui/.
Opening form [ORDERS] in company [usdemo].
Opened form [Sales Orders].

Subforms of Sales Orders.
  --Opening subform
    {"title":"Attachments"}.
```

So I wasn't expecting the subsequent call to startSubForm to work:

```
pdq.subForm = function (FormName, pdqFormLoad) {

    console.log("Opening subform [%s] in company [%s].", FormName, _config.company);

    eventEmitter.on('pdqFormLoad', pdqFormLoad);
    priority.startSubForm(FormName, pdq.ErrorCallback, pdq.onUpdateFields).then(
        function (form) {        
            eventEmitter.emit('pdqFormLoad', form);

        },

        function () {
            eventEmitter.emit('pdqFormLoad', null);

        }
    );
}
```

What I wasn't expecting was for the package to deny all knowledge of the function:

```
Opening subform [Attachments] in company [usdemo].
(node:38560) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: 
Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): 
TypeError: priority.startSubForm is not a function
```

Any suggestions please @NeomiBushary, @Leor?

---

Update 2:
Ok, I'm now receiving the Sub-form ID and passing it to my function, along with the parent form, if any exists like this:

```
pdq.startForm = function (parent, FormName, pdqFormLoad) {

    eventEmitter.on('pdqFormLoad', pdqFormLoad);

    if (parent) {
        console.log("Parent form.\n%j", parent);
        parent.startSubForm(FormName, pdq.ErrorCallback, pdq.onUpdateFields).then(
            function (subform) {
                console.log("Sub form.\n%j", subform);
                eventEmitter.emit('pdqFormLoad', subform);

            },

            function () {
                eventEmitter.emit('pdqFormLoad', null);

            }
        );

    } else {
        priority.formStart(
            FormName,
            pdq.ErrorCallback,
            pdq.onUpdateFields,
            _config.company,
            0
        ).then(
            function (form) {
                eventEmitter.emit('pdqFormLoad', form);

            },

            function () {
                eventEmitter.emit('pdqFormLoad', null);

            }
        );

    };

}
```

This works for the call to formStart (parent==null). But when I call the startSubForm on the parent form (created by the formstart call), the resulting form object passed to the [onSuccsess] event is the parent form, not the requested sub-form.

An example...

```
parent.startSubForm("EXTFILES" ...
```

where parent is a form object created by formStart with parent.name = "ORDERS"

```
...then(
            function (subform) {
```

subform.name is also = "ORDERS"

Any ideas please?

---

Update 3:

Here's the parent / returned sub-form objects.

**Parent form.**

```
{
  "name": "ORDERS",
  "title": "Sales Orders",
  "subForms": {
    "EXTFILES": { "title": "Attachments" },
    ...
  },
  "activations": {
    ...
  },
  "columns": {
    ...
  },
  "oneline": 0,
  "isquery": 0,
  "ishtml": 0
}
```

**Sub form.**

```
{
  "name": "ORDERS",
  "title": "Sales Orders",
  "subForms": {
    "EXTFILES": { "title": "Attachments" },
    ...
  },
  "activations": {
    ...
  },
  "columns": {
    ...
  },
  "oneline": 0,
  "isquery": 0,
  "ishtml": 0
}
```

---

Update 4

Another example of a call to `startSubForm` returning the parent form, rather than the requested subform...

```
    function thisapp(){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            formStart('APPGEN', showMessage, updateFields).then(
                function (appgen) {

                    var thisQuery = QueryValue();
                    thisQuery.field="APPNAME";
                    thisQuery.fromval=config.appname;

                    var f = FilterValue();
                    f.QueryValues.push(thisQuery);

                    appgen.Filter = f;
                    appgen.getRows(0).then(
                        function(rows) {
                            appgen.setActiveRow(1);
                            resolve(appgen);
                        },
                        function(message){
                            reject(message)
                        }
                    )                   
                },

                function(message){
                    reject(message)
                }

            )

        });
    };

    function appForms(appgen, formName){
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            appgen.startSubForm("APPFORMS", showMessage, updateFields).then(
                function (appforms) {

                    var thisQuery = QueryValue();
                    thisQuery.field="FATENAME";
                    thisQuery.fromval=formName;

                    var f = FilterValue();
                    f.QueryValues.push(thisQuery);

                    appforms.Filter = f;
                    resolve(appforms);
                },

                function(message){
                    reject(message)
                }

            )
        });
    };

    function priorityReady() {

        login(config).then(
            function(){
                thisapp().then(
                    function(appgen){
                        appForms(appgen, "DOCUMENTS_Q").then(
                            function(appforms){
                                appforms.getRows(0).then(
                                    function(rows) {
                                        console.log(rows);
                                    }, showMessage
                                )
                            }, showMessage
                        )
                    }, showMessage
                )
            }, showMessage
        )

    }
```

Comment: About your update: Can you `console.log` the parent form that calls `parent.startSubForm("EXTFILES" ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer both questions one by one:

First the `subForms` property that exists on the opened `form` object is a javascript object where the keys are the internal subforms names, and values are an object with the subforms titles.

```
for (subformName in form.subForms) {                        
     console.log("--Opening subform: " + subformName);
}
```

will output:

```
Subforms of Sales Orders.
  --Opening subform EXTFILES
```

In order to retrieve a `form` object with all properties for a subform, you will have to start the subform with `startSubForm`.

Second, the `startSubForm` function is an instance method of the parent `form` object retrieved by `formStart`. It is not a global method of the priority module.

So instead you should do:

```
formStart('ORDERS',...)
  .then(function(form) {//retrieve the parent form object
     form.startSubForm('EXTFILES') //start a subform for that form
      .then(function(subform) { ...}
  });
```

`startSubForm` starts a subform for a particular form, that's why is should be called on the specific `form` object of it's parent form. In order to start a sub-sub form, the `startSubForm` should be called on the `subform` object etc.

Generally I would mention that all methods to perform actions for a particular form are instance methods of the `form` object. The list of the available  instance methods is documented [here](https://prioritysoftware.github.io/api/form/)